# Cannot load GLB models because of "RangeError: Invalid typed array length"

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

The GLB file models (e.g.: Flamingo.glb, Parrot.glb, Stork.glb) used in the examples of Three.js official site.
I got the following error and the models were not displayed. These are displayed locally without any problem.
Is copyright the cause of this problem?

log trace below:

```
> GLTFLoader.js:153<br>RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 210<br>
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)<br>
    at GLTFLoader.js:2378<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 0)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 2)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 0)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 1)<br>
_onError @ GLTFLoader.js:153<br><br>
GLTFLoader.js:153 <br>RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 182<br>
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)<br>
    at GLTFLoader.js:2378<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 0)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 2)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 0)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 1)<br>
_onError @ GLTFLoader.js:153<br><br>
GLTFLoader.js:153 <br>RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 156<br>
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)<br>
    at GLTFLoader.js:2378<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 0)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 2)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 0)<br>
    at async Promise.all (/index 1)<br>
_onError @ GLTFLoader.js:153
```

Comment: Related: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-loader-issue-invalid-typed-array-length-4/13442

Comment: Thank you for the hint. That means I have to pass the ArrayBuffer into GLTFLoader?

Comment: I think you should first check how your backend serves the glTF asset.

Comment: BTW: Consider to demonstrate the issue with a live example e.g. via https://glitch.com/create-project. Glitch allows you to upload assets.

Comment: When I tried it with the glitch you taught me, GLB worked. Is it related to the use of Node.js?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Do you mind trying a different web server?

Comment: Yes. If possible, I want to use the current server.  Is there a way to load glb model without using Node.js?

Comment: Basic web server options for different languages/tools are explained here: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Is there no choice but to open my site using a local server?
I would like to use a rental server that does not support Node.js.

Comment: Of course you can deploy your app on a rental server but the actual deployment depends on what kind of server you choose. I'm afraid I can't help you in that regard.

Comment: I understand. I will change it to VPS to use Node.js. Thank you very much for making time in your busy schedule. You've been very helpful.